# PostgreSQL Inner Join on the same table + second table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

If this is a stupid question, forgive me, I'm not very familiar with PostgreSQL.

I've collected inventory data from used car dealerships in my area and stored it in a postgreSQL table. I've got a second table with particular details regarding certain makes and models. For example:

The dealership table is structured like so:

```
-----------------------------------------
| Dealership | Make | Model | Year | ID |
----------------------------------------|
|     A      | Ford | F250  | 2003 |  1 |
|     A      | Chevy| Cobalt| 2005 |  2 |
|     B      | Ford | F250  | 2003 |  1 |
|     B      | Dodge| Chrgr | 2012 |  3 |
-----------------------------------------
```

The details table is structured like so:

```
-----------------------------------------
|     ID     | DetailA| DetailB| DetailC|
-----------------------------------------
|     1      |  data  |  data  |  data  |
|     2      |  data  |  data  |  data  |
|     3      |  data  |  data  |  data  |
|     4      |  data  |  data  |  data  |
-----------------------------------------
```

My goal is to retrieve vehicle matches from multiple dealerships and display the appropriate details. In the above example, I would like to see:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
| Make | Model | Year | DetailA | DetailB | DetailC |
-----------------------------------------------------
| Ford | F250  | 2003 |   data  |  data   |  data   |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

With this result, I will know that both A and B havea  2003 Ford F250 for sale, and can view the related details of the vehicle.

I've tried many different queries, but most are variations on something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    dealership_table.make,
    dealership_table.model,
    dealership_table.year
            details_table.detaila,
            details_table.detailb,
            details_table.detailc
FROM
    dealership_table
INNER JOIN
    details_table
    ON
    dealership_table.id = details_table.id
WHERE
     dealership_table.dealership = 'A'
     OR
     dealership_table.dealership = 'B'
```

However this returns all of the distinct matches from the table where dealership is either A or B. I've tried multiple inner-joins, but I an error complaining `details_table` is specified multiple times.

If I'm doing something really silly, I apologize. Like I said before, I'm pretty much an SQL noob.

What am I doing wrong? How should I go about retrieving the desired results? Any suggestions, solutions, or advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: "With this result I will know that both dealership A and B have a 2003 Ford F250 for sale." It seem to me that you already kwew that from the  first table alone.

Comment: You actually don't know that both dealerships have the same model in inventory. This query will only find models that EITHER dealership have in stock. Use AND instead of OR to specify what models both A and B have in stock. Take heed of Chad's answer as well.

Comment: @leonbloy I'm sorry, let me re-phrase that. "With this result, I will know that both A and B havea  2003 Ford F250 for sale, and can view the related details of the vehicle."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write:

```
SELECT dealership_table1.make,
       dealership_table1.model,
       dealership_table1.year,
       details_table.detaila,
       details_table.detailb,
       details_table.detailc
  FROM dealership_table dealership_table1
  JOIN dealership_table dealership_table2
    ON dealership_table1.make  = dealership_table2.make
   AND dealership_table1.model = dealership_table2.model
   AND dealership_table1.year  = dealership_table2.year
  JOIN details_table
    ON dealership_table.id = details_table.id
 WHERE dealership_table1.dealership = 'A'
   AND dealership_table1.dealership = 'B'
;
```

(Note that the `FROM dealership_table dealership_table1` and `JOIN dealership_table dealership_table2` set up distinct "aliases", so you can use the same table multiple different times in the same query without getting name-conflicts.)

Answer (score 4):

I may be misunderstanding your table layout, but I think you should consider changing to a different structure. Here's what I would propose:

**Vehicle**:

```
----------------------------
| ID | Make | Model | Year |
----------------------------
| 1  | Ford | F250  | 2003 |
| 2  | Chevy| Cobalt| 2005 |
| 3  | Dodge| Chrgr | 2012 |
----------------------------
```

**Dealership**:

```
----------------------------
| Dealership | ID | Detail |
----------------------------
|     A      |  1 |  data  |
|     A      |  2 |  data  |
|     B      |  1 |  data  |
|     B      |  3 |  data  |
----------------------------
```

This way you're not storing vehicle information (make/model/year) in more than one place.

Here's how you would write your desired query given the above schema:

```
SELECT Make, Model, Year, A.Detail, B.Detail, C.Detail
FROM Vehicle V
LEFT OUTER JOIN Dealership A on A.Dealership = 'A' and A.id = V.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Dealership B on B.Dealership = 'B' and B.id = V.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Dealership C on C.Dealership = 'C' and C.id = V.id
```

Comment: I agree with you, but I don't think that actually addresses the OP's problem at all. Yes, (s)he should normalize his/her schema, but even with a normalized schema (s)he'll still need a self-join.